# I am getting a 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' error for my audio files in my project

Tags: javascript, audio, path

I am working on my project and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong with the audio file paths to make them work on the GitHub repository. They are working on my local machine, but I can't hear them on the GitHub version.

Here is my GitHub link:

https://milfords.github.io/js-dev-final-capstone-starter-simon-says/

And the actual link to the repository with the code:

https://github.com/Milfords/js-dev-final-capstone-starter-simon-says

Currently, I have my file paths for the audio files in my index.js file as such:

```
const winner = new Audio('../assets/winner-winner-sound.mp3');
```

And in a different part of the index.js file I have some of them setup as a property in an object like this:

```
sound: new Audio('../assets/simon-says-sound-1.mp3')
```

I have tried changing the file path many times using examples like this:

```
../../assets/simon-says-sound-1.mp3
./assets/simon-says-sound-1.mp3
./js-dev-final-capstone-starter-simon-says/assets/simon-says-sound-1.mp3
../js-dev-final-capstone-starter-simon-says/assets/simon-says-sound-1.mp3
```

I have seen similar questions on stack overflow, but haven't found any solutions that are working for my particular problem.

I was expecting to see the audio files showing in the assets folder of the project, but when the GitHub version loads, it is missing the audio files from the assets in the sources tab in the chrome dev tools.

I also have a photo in the styles.css file that is in the same directory folder as the index.js using a similar file path and the photo from the CSS file is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

This method uses Github permalink instead relative URLs.

```js
const winner = new Audio('https://github.com/Milfords/js-dev-final-capstone-starter-simon-says/blob/d6e88518200b876d631bed1e76c1430095fb3a43/assets/winner-winner-sound.mp3');
```

## Method 2

Add the following to your `index.html` file inside the `body` tag but **before** `<script src="./src/index.js"></script>`:

```html
<audio id="winnerAudio" src="audio/winner-winner-sound.mp3"></audio>
```

In `index.js`:

```
const winner = document.getElementById("winnerAudio");

// winner.play()
```

## Method 3

```js
import AudioFile from "../assets/winner-winner-sound.mp3"; // at top of JS file
const winner = new Audio(AudioFile);
```

Comment: I was able to use method 2 to solve the issue. Thanks for the input.